# PHP: Sort cookies alphabetically?

Tags: php, cookies

I've created a shopping cart where the products are stored in cookies, and I display all the cookies using this loop:

```
foreach($_COOKIE['products'] as $productId => $productQuantity) {
```

The problem is, every time add 1 to the quantity (so when I change the cookie value), that cookie ends up last in the list of the cart's products. How can I sort these cookies alphabetically, so the order will always be the same?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you want to sort it by key. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: @mkaatman That solves the problem, didn't know it was that easy! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

It will do that, what you want.

---

This is a Community wiki, since this is solved, and still not shown as this. Feel free to contribute.